# Magento2: existing quote doesn't load through a cron job

Tags: magento2, addtocart, cron, cronjobs

I want to get an existing quote through a cron job, but it returns null.

Want get through this `$this->quoteFactory->create()->loadByCustomer($custoemrId)`

or

`$this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId)`.

It works without cron job but I need through a cron job.

```
$checkCartExist = $this->quoteFactory->create()->loadByCustomer($customerId);
  $checkCartExist->getAllVisibleItems();
  var_dump($checkCartExist->getData()); // returns 0 through a cron


 if (!$checkCartExist['entity_id']) {
      $cartId = $this->cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart(); //Create empty cart
      $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cartId); // load empty cart quote

 } else {

      $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->getForCustomer($customerId);
 }
```

Cron works because each time it created a new quote item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try with below code in your cron file for getting quote items with customer id.

```
protected $quoteFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
) {
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    $this->quoteModel=$quoteModel;
}

public function getQuoteCollection($customerId)
{
    $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId);
    return $quote;
}
```

***Hope it helps!!!***

Comment: Sumit, thanks for answer, $customerQuote->getAllItems() getAllItems method  is not defined

Comment: Updated my answer for getting the quote of the customer with customer id.

Answer (score 1):

Instead using Quote factory, use  quote Repositoryrep`Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface::getForCustomer`

This method needs two param `$customerId, array $sharedStoreIds = []`

**So you have to provide those two parameters**

> ```
> /**
> * Where $this->quote is instance of Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
> */
>
> $this->quote->getForCustomer({CustomerId}, [{MyStoreId}]);
> ```

Comment: Not get quote using cron. M2.4